# What is the *best* way to express that an email contains an attachment?

Tags: formality, email

I'm wondering what is the *best* way to express that an email contains an attachment. I'd like to have a formal example, and an informal example.

For example:

Is this informal?

> Attached you can find the document...

Is this too formal? too old school?

> Please find enclosed the document...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most email applications will have a clear indication (e.g. a clip icon) when the email has attachments. So you don't really have to explain that. Instead, you can focus on describing what exactly is attached to the email. For example:

> The attached file is the document that
> you requested.
>
> The attachment is a draft Power
> Point presentation.

These can be used in formal and informal emails.

Answer (score 11):

For informal emails you could use:

> I've attached...

For more formal emails you could write:

> Please find attached...

For a discussion of enclosed vs attached please see:

http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/22264-difference-between-enclosed-attached.html

Comment: I agree completely. I often write something like, 'I have attached a quote as discussed'.

Answer (score 2):

You may keep it concrete and polite (usable in formal/informal speech)

- You may refer to the attached document for details
- Please refer to the attached document
- Kindly refer to the attached document

This will also cover your back against users arguing they missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Informal:

> Please see the attached document.

Formal:

> Please find attached the 
>   agreement.